# Discarding 4 precision points?

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-point-precision

I have a floating point number, but I only want the number till 2 points of precision. How do I get this in C++?

```
float foo(float num) { // num=1234.567891
    // code
    return num2;           // returns 1234.560000
}
```

Comment: not a C++ guy, but can you multiply it times 100 and cast as an integer, then cast as a float and divide by 100?

Comment: Is this an option? `int(num * 100) / (float)100`

Comment: May I ask for what purpose? If you merely want to print two places after the decimal point, simply look up output formatting.

Comment: Note that it is not possible to return exactly 1234.56, as that is not representable as a float. You can round, but not exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be:

```
float foo(float num) {
    return floor(num * 100) / 100;
}
```

You may also consider:

```
float foo(float num) {
    return (int)(num * 100) / 100.0f;
}
```

There might be differences with negative numbers. Only information I can get from your question is that for positive numbers you want `floor` (and not `round` for example).

Comment: Do I typecast like (int)(expression) or like static_int(expression)?
Or are they same?

Comment: `(int)(expression)` is C style. `static_cast<int>(expression)` is C++ style. Whichever you choose should be the same (Note: I like C). If you have `dynamic_cast<>` and similar constructs, I advise the second form since it gives your code more regularity.

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to round a floating point number to a certain number of decimal places, by multiplying and rounding/truncating.

So `num = floor(num * 100.f) / 100.f;` would try to truncate to two decimal places.

However note that this is not the same as fixing the *precision* of the float. By definition the decimal point in a floating point number *floats*. And you only have around 7 digits of precision.

So your original number cannot be as precise as "1234.567891" - this is too much precision for a float.

And perhaps more importantly, your output from such a function may also not be precise. "1234.56" cannot be exactly represented by a float, so the returned value will not be "1234.560000".

The larger the integer portion of the number, the less digits can be represented after the decimal point. Indeed, even a moderately large number cannot represent any fractional part at all.

Answer (score 0):

Floating-point types have their own internal precision. You can't change it. You can fiddle with the value in various ways, but ultimately the floating-point types manage their own precision, and you won't succeed in limiting what they do. Even if you manage to force a bunch of zeros into the low bits of some value, subsequent computations will still use the full precision, and you've only introduced some random noise into the computation.

What you **can** do is control the number of significant digits on **input** and **output**. And that's almost always the right way to manage precision.